# Does not respond to the sum function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, onclick

[image][image]

i have enabled OnClick feature with javascript.
but in the final process, namely the summation, the code that I inserted did not respond.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="tambahgajiModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tambahgajiModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="tambahfungsiModal">Tambah Gaji Karyawan</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="/gaji/insert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <!--on clik on change javascript-->
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                function golongan() {
                                    var data = document.getElementById("gol").value;
                                    document.getElementById("tunjangan_gol").value = data;
                                }

                                function fungsional() {
                                    var data = document.getElementById("fungsi").value;
                                    document.getElementById("tunjangan_fungsi").value = data;
                                }

                                function struktural() {
                                    var data = document.getElementById("struktur").value;
                                    document.getElementById("tunjangan_struktur").value = data;
                                }

                                function sum() {
                                    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('tunjangan_gol').value;
                                    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('tunjangan_fungsi').value;
                                    var txtThreeNumberValue = document.getElementById('tunjangan_struktur').value;
                                    var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtThreeNumberValue);
                                    if (!isNaN(result)) {
                                        document.getElementById('total').value = result;
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="nama" type="text" class="form-control @error('nama') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('nama') }}">
                                    <option>-- Nama Karyawan --</option>
                                    @foreach ($karyawan as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->nama }}">{{ $data->nama }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('nama')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="gol" id="gol" type="text" onclick="golongan()" class="form-control @error('gol') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('gol') }}">
                                    <option>-- Golongan dan M K G --</option>
                                    @foreach ($golongan as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->tunjangan_gol }}">{{ $data->gol }} | {{ $data->mkg }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class=" invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('gol')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="tunjangan_gol" type="number" id="tunjangan_gol" onclick="sum()" placeholder="Gaji Pokok" class="form-control @error('tunjangan_gol') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('tunjangan_gol') }}" readonly>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('tunjangan_gol')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="jbt_fungsi" id="fungsi" type="text" onclick="fungsional()" class="form-control @error('jbt_fungsi') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('jbt_fungsi') }}">
                                    <option>-- Jabatan Fungsional --</option>
                                    @foreach ($fungsi as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->tunjangan_fungsi }}">{{ $data->jbt_fungsi }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('gol')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="tunjangan_fungsi" type="number" id="tunjangan_fungsi" onclick="sum()" placeholder="Tunjangan Fungsional" class="form-control @error('tunjangan_fungsi') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('tunjangan_fungsi') }}" readonly>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('tunjangan_fungsi')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="jbt_struktur" id="struktur" onclick="struktural()" class="form-control @error('jbt_struktur') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('jbt_struktur') }}">
                                    <option>-- Jabatan Struktural & Fungsional --</option>
                                    @foreach ($struktur as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->tunjangan_struktur }}">{{ $data->jbt_struktur }} | {{ $data->jbt_fungsi }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('jbt_struktur')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="tunjangan_struktur" type="number" id="tunjangan_struktur" onclick="sum()" placeholder="Tunjangan Struktural" class="form-control @error('tunjangan_struktur') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('tunjangan_struktur') }}" readonly>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('tunjangan_struktur')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="total_gaji" type="number" id="total" onclick="sum()" placeholder="Total Gaji" class="form-control @error('total_gaji') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('total_gaji') }}" readonly>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('total_gaji')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there something i missed ? i think this is correct, maybe there is a mistake in my code insert.....

thank you for taking your time both in viewing and responding to my question.

Comment: Do you get js errors in the console?

Comment: oh yes, in the console there is some error info, but how do I show it. in the comment column this does not support uploading images

Comment: edit your question.

Comment: @GertB. question has been updated

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I see you are using a modal. could it be that there are multiple modals on the page so the ID is not unique?

Comment: @GertB.no, the id is already unique. because it can already be used to trigger onClick

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your values with console log, then console the sum also, then push it to the sum input field. as far as i can see, your code is fine and its working in my pc in raw html. so you may select the wrong id, check that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="num1" type="number" id="num1" onkeyup="sum()" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" value="" />
    <input name="num1" type="number" id="num3" onkeyup="sum()" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" value="" />
    <input name="num1" type="number" id="num2" onkeyup="sum()" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" value="" />
    <input name="num1" type="number" id="total" onkeyup="sum()" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" value="" />

    <script>
        function sum() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById("num1").value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById("num2").value;
            var txtThreeNumberValue = document.getElementById("num3").value;
            var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtThreeNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById("total").value = result;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: clear,
what actually happens is, I have a form with a dropdown select feature. so i need to add onclick in every attribute related to sum() function.

but the problem is, the total from sum() must also be clicked before the value appears..

i just edited my question for the latest code

Comment: done,
I'm trying to combine onclick for 2 functions in each combobox attribute

Comment: Is you problem solved?

Comment: no,
I'm confused because the value entered in the select does not match the input in the form

`<option value="{{ $data->support_structure }}">{{ $data->jbt_structure }} | {{ $data->jbt_function }}</option>

like this
<option value="{{ $data->support_structure }}">{{ $data->jbt_structure }} | {{ $data->jbt_function }}</option>`

if my value changes according to the label, javascript onclick is not active